# formatting a Java for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of Boat objects from the main method parameter list, and then assign the name given in the args array to the boat with .name. What is the correct way to format this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        Boat args[i] = new Boat();
        args[i].name = args[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Where is `args` defined?  What is the type of `name`?

Comment: You're incorrectly reusing `args`. It's the `String` array that's passed into `main`; you need a separate `Boat boats[] = new Boat[args.length];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Boat boat = new Boat();
boat.name = args[i];
// and then do something with the Boat, I guess...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) { Boat
    args[i] = new Boat();
```

you're running into scope issues.  You need to change the name of your `Boat` array and declare it outside the loop (so it's only created once).

```
Boat armada[args.length];
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    armada[i] = new Boat();
    armada[i].name = args[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Boat[] boats = new Boat[args.length];
  for (int i=0; i< args.length; i++) {
    boats[i] = new Boat();
    boats[i].name = args[i];
  }
}
```

I made one assumption that your `Boat` class had a `public` field called `name`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the array of boats

```
Boat[] boats = new Boat[args.length];
```

Then, iterate over the args to get the names, and for each name, create a new boat with the name and save it in a position of the boats array

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    Boat boat = new Boat(); //Create new boat
    boat.name = args[i]; //Give the name to the new boat
    boats[i] = boat; //And save it into the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Add a new constructor which accepts name as argument and try the following`

```
        Boat[] boat = new Boat[args.length]; 
            for (int iter = 0; iter < args.length; iter++) {
                boat[iter] = new Boat(args[iter]);
        }
```